# Python project architecture

Tags: python, architecture

I'm a java developer new to python. In java, you can access all classes in the same directory without having to import them.

I am trying to achieve the same behavior in python. Is this possible?

I've tried various solutions, for example by importing everything in a file which I import everywhere. That works, but I have to type `myClass = rootFolder.folder2.folder3.MyClass()` each time I want to access a foreign class.

Could you show me an example for how a python architecture over several directories works? Do you *really* have to import all the classes you need in each file?

Imagine that I'm writing a web framework. Will the users of the framework have to import everything they need in their files?

Comment: from the zen of python: "explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: In addition to Stargazer's answer, don't forget that Python allows you to have multiple unrelated classes in the same file. So you don't need to split things up as much as you do in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put everything into a folder (doesn't matter the name), and make sure that that folder has a file named __init__.py (the file can be empty).

Then you can add the following line to the top of your code:

```
from myfolder import *
```

That should give you access to everything defined in that folder without needing to give the prefix each time.

You can also have multiple depths of folders like this:

```
from folder1.folder2 import *
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I just looked at Django, and they import what they need when they need it. Guess that might be _the_ way to do it.

Comment: -1: using `from ... import *` is horrible style, either specify explicitly what to import, e.g. `from test import test1, test2`. Or better don't use `from` at all and optionally just shorten the names like `import test.inner_test as it`.

Comment: I agree that it is not good style, but that wasn't what he was asking.